# Make Emacs open with three frames by default for OCaml editing

Tags: emacs, window, frame

I wish that if I open a **.ml** (OCaml file), or enter Tuareg mode (a mode for OCaml programming), then the frame should be split like shown in the picture.

[image: emacs in tri]

- Left is the main.
- Top right is secondary.
- Bottom right is a terminal like env (in here it is a OCaml top level)

Can I set emacs these actions by default?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility: use a [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) ***desktop bookmark***.  And then invoke the bookmark from the mode hook.

If you need to do more than what Desktop provides, to set up the buffers and window/frame configuration you want, then you can use a *sequence* bookmark that combines a *desktop* bookmark with, say, a *function* bookmark. IOW, you can use a bookmark to execute arbitrary code, and desktop bookmarks give you a quick and easy way to flip among different desktop setups.